# ASP.Net Core Authentication Providers

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, google-oauth, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an ASP.Net Core 2.0 MVC using authentication providers as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/

On localhost (i.e. when run via Visual Studio 2017) all works well.  However, after deploying to Azure I found that the login providers stopped working (despite my setting up appropriate callback URIs; e.g. for Google I have `https://localhost:44357/signin-google` but also `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/signin-google`, `https://example.com/signin-google`, and `https://www.example.com/signin-google` (as well as having setup the `example.com` domain and its `www` subdomain in Azure and configured SSL covering these domains).  For Twitter I've changed the setup to the www subdomain only (as only 1 callback URL's allowed), and for LinkedIn I only have the domain and subdomain (i.e. I had to remove localhost; as LinkedIn only allows callback URI's under a single domain).  I've also configured those keys/values which had been in my `secrets.json` under the Azure App Service's `Application Settings`.

#### Symptoms

On first login (aka registration), the user clicks the relevant provider's button after which new user entry appears in the `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetUserLogins` tables, and the user is directed to the page where they can associate their email.  However, they're not logged in at that point; just registered.  Subsequent attempts take them back to the email registration form; only clicking the `Register` button then returns an error message stating that the email's already registered (which is correct); but the user's still not signed in to the site.

I have the same issue with all providers; though after proving this focussed most of my ongoing on Google, just to limit the number of changing variables.

The only significant change I've made from the example was to refactor code in `Startup.cs` so that each provider's encapsulated in it's own method; so `ConfigureServices` contains:

```
ConfigureServicesAuthFacebook(services);
ConfigureServicesAuthGoogle(services);
ConfigureServicesAuthTwitter(services);
ConfigureServicesAuthMicrosoft(services);
ConfigureServicesAuthLinkedIn(services);
```

... and those methods look like this:

```
#region Authentication Providers
public void ConfigureServicesAuthFacebook(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(x =>
    {
        x.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:Id"];
        x.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:Secret"];
    });
}
public void ConfigureServicesAuthGoogle(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(x =>
    {
        x.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:Id"];
        x.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:Secret"];
    });
}
public void ConfigureServicesAuthTwitter(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddTwitter(x =>
    {
        x.ConsumerKey = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:Id"];
        x.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Twitter:Secret"];
    });
}
public void ConfigureServicesAuthMicrosoft(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(x =>
    {
        x.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Id"];
        x.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Secret"];
    });
}
public void ConfigureServicesAuthLinkedIn(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth("LinkedIn", x =>
    {
        x.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:Id"];
        x.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:LinkedIn:Secret"];
        x.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-linkedin"); 
        x.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization";
        x.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
        x.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,email-address,picture-url)";
        //x.Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" };
    });
}
#endregion Authentication Providers
```

#### Question

How can I debug this issue given I cannot recreate the problem on localhost.  Any hints on what the issue may be?

Comment: I think this depends on how you have the registration pages setup on your site.  The first thing you are doing is just associating the account with the users account on your system after that you need to do the actuall ExternalLoginSignInAsync

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo; following your tip I added some code to investigate what that method returned and found that `result.IsNotAllowed` was set to `true`; but there was no logic to handle that scenario.  Now looking into the cause of that; but this has got me moving again; thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is your user first must assoicate their Google account with the user on your system.  It sounds like this is working for you.

After that is done your code should preform some kind of `ExternalLoginSignInAsync`  however this kind of depends on how you have your system set up.

Out of the box, where `IsNotAllowed` is `true` this means the email or phone number associated with the account which needs to be confirmed has not yet been confirmed.  See [ASN.NET Core 2.0 Facebook authentication ExternalLoginSignInAsync Fails (IsNotAllowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268027/asn-net-core-2-0-facebook-authentication-externalloginsigninasync-fails-isnotal?rq=1)

Take a look at the `AccountController` method `ExternalLoginConfirmation` and you'll see:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser(model.Email) { Email = model.Email };
```

Assuming you're happy for those signing up with existing logon providers, amend this to:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser(model.Email) { Email = model.Email, EmailConfirmed = true };
```